How to Scrape Dynamically-Loaded Store URLs from Web Page
I'm working on a web scraping project and I'm attempting to extract a list of store URLs from the following page: https://maroof.sa/businesses.
Here are the methods I've tried thus far, but without success:
Using BeautifulSoup and Requests in Python to parse the HTML, but I was unable to locate the correct tags/classes that contain the store URLs.
Employing Selenium to wait for JavaScript to render the store links and then extract them, but the appropriate elements

Help us to help you - Please improve your question and provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks In addition, please, take the [tour], read [ask].

You can try:
import json
import requests


url = "https://api.thiqah.sa/maroof/public/api/app/business/search?keyword=&businessTypeId=&businessTypeSubCategoryId=&regionId=&cityId=&certificationType=&sortBy=2&sortDirection=2&sorting=&skipCount=0&maxResultCount=10"
headers = {"apikey": "c1qesecmag8GSbxTHGRjfnMFBzAH7UAN"}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i in data["items"]:
    print(i["nameAr"])
    print(f"https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/{i['id']}")
    print()

Prints:
متجر بياض
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/229217

متجر مروه
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/48066

المتسوقة مآثر
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/168551

متجر أحمد للأنظمة الصوتية والألكترونيات
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/25650

متعب للأرقام المميزة
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/253838

متجر شوب تتش
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/246531

مؤسسة ماجد عبدالله الشهراني للمقاولات
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/244174

شركة إنجاز للخدمات 
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/276939

موقع عاملتي الرقمي
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/261892

مندوبكم
https://maroof.sa/businesses/details/112807


EDIT: Screenshot:


This Works Good. how to get the URLs of the next Pages?
Also, how to get this API? MAny thanks

@ahmedsayed To get next pages I'd try to increase the skipCount= parameter in URL. You can see the API URL in Web Developer Tools when you switch to Network Tab (and click to load next results).

if you could provide a screenshot of the network tab that previews the load next results it would be Great!

@ahmedsayed I've put screenshot in the answer.
